# Docker-compose - memsql container - backend connection problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, singlestore

I am trying to fire up a dockerized environment on an Ubuntu machine containing a memsql+java backend using docker-compose. 
  My docker compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  memsql:
    image: memsql/quickstart
    container_name: memsql
    environment:
      MEMSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passW
      MEMSQL_DATABASE: db
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./memsql:/var/lib/memsql

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: java-dockerfile
    image: backend:1
    container_name: backend
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
      - memsql
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/external
    command: ["java", "-jar", "server.jar", "-Xms1024m", " -Xmx2048m", "> /external/server.log"]
```

When I try to fire it up, the backend is not able to connect to my memsql container - it gives the connection refused error.

The memsql container itself is running, I can access it (`docker exec -it memsql /bin/bash`), check the logs (`/memsql/master/tracelogs# cat memsql.log`), log into it (`mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --prompt="memsql> "`).
Indeed, it does not create the specified DB and when I log in, it doesn't ask for the specified password.

I tried also different network-specific solutions, like using a defined network or setting the network mode to "host", but none of them worked.
I suspect it is a memsql related problem (yes, I know the image I am using is marked as deprecated), but can't seem what could be. In the logs the only error I found was:

```
ERROR: Thread 115082: Fn: Waiting for node to catch up with cluster state before starting replication management.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you have the application configured to connect to the database?  Can you connect to it using the `mysql` command-line client from your host?

Comment: Also note that the [Docker Hub memsql/quickstart page](https://hub.docker.com/r/memsql/quickstart) has a prominent notice that the image is deprecated.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a java backend, and in my application.yml file I have
`jdbcUrl: jdbc:mariadb://memsql:3306/db`
If I use an IP and do the connection to a DB on another machine, my backend connects and everything is OK, so for some reason the container is not seen.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out the problem: the memsql container takes a couple of seconds until also the clusters are started, but my backend container tries to connect to it beforehand, thus the connection refused error. Now I just need to figure out a way how to add a delay or healthcheck into the equation. The solutions found till now did not help.